# Set Timezone for Rake tasks same as the default timezone in RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I've several rake tasks which depend on the timezone.

Rails app default timezone is +5:30 GMT, timezone is proper in rails app but in rake tasks, the default timezone is GMT, how do i change the default timezone in rake tasks?

Comment: are you depending on the rails ```:environment``` task? this should setup everything as in your rails server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails app automatically converts the sql query to

```
WHERE (orders.created_at >= '2013-01-08 18:30:00.000000' AND orders.created_at <= '2013-01-09 18:29:59.999999')
```

I need to manually edit the query